# Can't display items that are store in the database if they have <p> tags

Tags: php

So I have this function that allows me to add a description to a topic and in the database it is storing it with `<p>` tags, and I can't figure out how to display the items in the following code:

```
$topicObj = new Topic($topic);
//Topic title
$title = $topicObj->title;
//Topic description
$description = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($topicObj->description));

$style = "<style>#topic_description{font-size:16px;background-color:#eee;} #description_wrapper{background-color:#eee;color:#666;height:100%;width:100%} #description_wrapper h2 {padding:16px 20px;} #description{max-height:100%;overflow:autowidth:95%;margin:10px auto;background-color: #FFFFFF;border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;padding: 10px;}</style>";
$output = $style . "<div id=\"description_wrapper\"><h2>$title</h2><div id=\"description\"></div>$description</div>";

$outp.= "<script>";

$outp.= "tmpan = new Ext.Panel ({
            title: '" . $tab->text . "',
            html: '$output',
            id: 'topic_description'
        });
        Ext.getCmp('tabsmain').add(tmpan);
        if (" . $tab->selected . " == 1) Ext.getCmp('tabsmain').setActiveTab(tmpan);";

$outp.= "</script>";

return $outp;
```

The problem is with the `$description` as in the DB it is

```
 <p>This is a test description</p>
```

Not really sure how to get the description to display.

If the `<p> tags` are gone, it works. So I guess my question is how would i go about grabbing that data and getting the tags off it.

Update: If I add a test variable with `<p>` tags it will display fine, and replace the `$description` with the test variable it displays it fine like I want, so im not sure way it is not displaying if I grab it from the DB

Comment: Are you saying this works `$description = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($topicObj->description));` but this doesn't: `$description = html_entity_decode($topicObj->description);`?

Comment: And what happens? Does the php throw an error or does it show up in the source but not in the browser view?

Comment: Or are you saying it won't pull/store in/from database with tag?

Comment: Neither of them work

Comment: No php error, I can see it in the source, but not in the outp. variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looks like the item it was pulling from the DB had whitespace at the end of it, so adding this `$description = rtrim($topicObj->description);` in the above fixed this issue for me, thanks for all the answers and comments

Answer (score 1):

if you don't misspell here only, it's not p tag problem.

your return value is **$outp**

and your description goes with **$output**

Comment: Im not sure i follow, it returns the outp because inside that is where $output is being called, I dont think that is the issue as if I go into the DB myself and remove the `<p>` tags then it outputs correctly

Comment: i think there's some transformation to values when insert/update to DB. check your db insert section whether transform(escape symbols) or not.

Comment: check this. copy and paste your real description from db to test variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use single quote and put description into the right div:

Change this

```
$output = $style . "<div id=\"description_wrapper\"><h2>$title</h2><div id=\"description\"></div>$description</div>";
```

To

```
$output = $style . '<div id="description_wrapper"><h2>'.$title.'</h2><div id="description">'.$description.'</div></div>";
```

If what you try to deal with are `<p></p>` tags only, then you didn't have to use the `strip_tags(html_entity_decode())`. It can display well.